how to make layout move up when keyboard show
I'm making an android app by kotlin. I want when the keyboard show, the screen auto move up and the element not being hided by the keyboard. My layout only contain FrameLayout and ConstrainLayout. I tried adding android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in AndroidManifest and programmatically but it not work.
This is my Fragment code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    tools:context=".SignInFragment"
    >
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/main_color"
            >

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/bg_intro"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_intro_image"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/intro_pic"
                            android:scaleType="center"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.3"/>


                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_intro_image2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="100dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/gradient_background"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_intro_image"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

                            />

                        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_intro_image2"
                            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"

                            >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_login"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Log In"
                                android:textSize="30sp"
                                android:textColor="@color/orange"
                                android:textAlignment="center"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/et_username_or_email"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="70dp"
                                android:autofillHints=""
                                android:hint="username or email"
                                android:ems="8"
                                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
                                android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:inputType="text"
                                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                                android:padding="20dp"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_login"/>

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/password"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="70dp"
                                android:hint="password"
                                android:ems="8"
                                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
                                android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:inputType="textPassword"
                                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                                android:padding="20dp"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/et_username_or_email"/>

                            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                                android:id="@+id/layout_forgot_password"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/password">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Forgot Password?"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Don't have an account?"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                                    />

                            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                                android:text="Log In"
                                android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_forgot_password"/>



                        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



</FrameLayout>

Fragment is implement in activity:
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".AuthenticationActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.example.app.SignInFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sign_in" />
    </FrameLayout>



</layout>

this is result:
enter image description here

did you add this " android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in your manifest? if not then try after adding this

@Hanif Shaikh it still not work

please add nested scroll view.
